# download windows 7 and windows 8 free and create a dvd with autorun

Tags: windows-installation

I want to download windows 7 and windows 8 properly and like to make a dvd which will help me to format windows 7 and windows 8 and also install window 7 and windows 8. I really very eager to know. I don't have any idea about this...

I want to format my system and install windows 8 but I don't have any dvd or downloaded file....

Comment: I am not going to flag this question as a duplicate as a single question ( because the author also wants to install Windows 7 ) but simply as not being on topic since the question isn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

The official download provider for Microsoft is DigitalRiver.

You can download the Windows ISOs from there. They are free to download (you could even use a mate's disk) but you must buy the right license for the version you require.

You cannot use Enterprise as it requires a volume licensing agreement - hence "Enterprise".

The license is the most important part of Windows and you must have one to legally use Windows - this is the part you buy.